# Quick return listview for iOS?

Tags: ios, listview, user-interface, ui-patterns

Are there any 3rd-party libraries out there that implement the quick return listview UI pattern for iOS? The ones I could find were all for Android. Here are some:

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView

https://github.com/felipecsl/QuickReturn

This probably developed as an Android concept, but it isn't unusual for devs to be inspired by UI patterns and port them to another platform. I'm not an iOS dev. If there is already an easy built-in mechanism to do this, it's even better.

Comment: I think you can easily do this with sectioned table view

Comment: Not sure if sections are what I'm looking for. This is more like a header that pops in and out of the screen upon scrolling.